# String split by newline

Tags: string, split, lua

I want to split a string by new lines and I want the split function to act like most other languages.

Input:

```lua
split('\nhello\nworld\n')
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "",
    "hello",
    "world",
    ""
}
```

I have tried following which return the result without the first and the last empty strings.

```lua
function split(text)
    local lines = {}

    for str in string.gmatch(text, "([^\n]+)") do
        table.insert(lines, str)
    end

    return lines
end
```

Comment: how do you expect to get 4 strings from 3 `\n` ?

Comment: @MikeV. Think of it in terms of an text editor. If you have empty string in the first line, "hello" and "world" in the second and third line, once again an empty. So that's 4 lines in total. Try string split in javascript or python. That's how it works

Comment: maybe so, but I think that in the text editor line 4 is artificially added, it is possible only to show the position of the cursor ..  in this case, I would also just add the end of the string and process it like this:  `string.gmatch(text.. "\n", "(.+)\n")`

Answer (score 2):

For Lua 5.3 and Lua 5.4 the "naive approach" (as LMD named it) works fine:

```
for w in ('\nhello\nworld\n'):gmatch"[^\n]*" do
```

For compatibility with old Lua regex implementation (Lua 5.1, Lua 5.2 and LuaJIT) another approach is needed:

```
for w in ('\nhello\nworld\n'..'\n'):gmatch"(.-)\n" do
```

Answer (score 0):

The **naive approach of using `string.gmatch(text, "([^\n]*)")` does not work on LuaJIT**; LuaJIT will randomly emit empty strings. Note also that you don't need the capture around the pattern; the entire pattern is captured implicitly.

Here is my `spliterator` function based on `string.find`:

```lua
function spliterator(str, delim, plain)
    assert(delim ~= "")
    local last_delim_end = 0

    -- Iterator of possibly empty substrings between two matches of the delimiter
    -- To exclude empty strings, filter the iterator or use `:gmatch"[...]+"` instead
    return function()
        if not last_delim_end then
            return
        end

        local delim_start, delim_end = str:find(delim, last_delim_end + 1, plain)
        local substr
        if delim_start then
            substr = str:sub(last_delim_end + 1, delim_start - 1)
        else
            substr = str:sub(last_delim_end + 1)
        end
        last_delim_end = delim_end
        return substr
    end
end
```

You can trivially use this to build a table:

```lua
function split(str, delim, plain)
    local t = {}
    for delimited in spliterator(str, delim, plain) do
        table.insert(t, delimited)
    end
    return t
end
```

Usage:

```lua
print(table.concat(split("\nhello\nworld\n", "\n"), ", "))
```

Note that usually you'd use `io.lines` / `file:lines` to iterate over the lines of a file.